# SQL get avg values by timestamp interval

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I have the following table format:

Data=[ID, value, timestamp]

ie:

```
ID | value | timestamp
1  |  20   | 2020-06-16 03:51:55
2  |  30   | 2020-06-16 04:00:00
3  |  10   | 2020-06-16 04:15:17
4  |  12   | 2020-06-16 05:23:35
```

I want to retrieve avg values by timestamp interval 30 minutes. In the above example, the query should return 2 avg values 20 and 12.  Is that possible?

Comment: What is your DBMS?

Comment: My DBMS is spark sql

Comment: [Edit] the question and show what you have tried and explain, in detail, what the problem is with it (error messages, unexpected result, etc.).

Comment: Please explain what "b timestamp interval 30 minutes" means?  What if the third row had a time of 04:22:00?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Spark SQL dialect, but you can use next approach:
For example PostgreSQL query:

```
create table t1 (ID serial, value int, "timestamp" timestamp);

insert into t1 (value, "timestamp") values
(20, '2020-06-16 03:51:55'),
(30, '2020-06-16 04:00:00'),
(10, '2020-06-16 04:15:17'),
(12, '2020-06-16 05:23:35');

select 
    avg(value) as avg_value, 
    -- convert date to unixtime divide by 1800 (seconds in 30 mins)
    -- round it and use value for groupping
    to_timestamp(round(extract(epoch from "timestamp")/1800)*1800)  as min30
from t1
group by min30;
```

[PostgreSQL fiddle](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=&sqlses=5474e52fd79f743690ba94f1cb44d19d&php_version=null&sql_version=psql11)